# Passing SAML token to a web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, model-view-controller, saml, adfs

I have an ASP.NET [MVC] application which has a claims based authentication scheme running. ADFS authenticates users and redirects back to the application domain with relevant token.

Now, I'd like to simulate this process from start to end. I was able to get a SAML 2.0 token object of type *GenericXmlSecurityToken* from ADFS via some powershell scripting but couldn't figure out how to create an SSL tunnel and pass the token to the application just to download the Index view. Any use of *net.webclient* ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send SAML 2.0 token to some SP application according with SAMLP standarad.
First, that application have to know how to handle SAML tokens. Second is to send it properly. If you want to send authentication response per instance you have to create HTTP POST request to your application on specific address where it is expecting it.

Take a look over SAML protocol documentation.